# SELECT WHERE id IN GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

How do I use a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause in combination with a `GROUP_CONCAT` such that the returned data will include any combination of items in the `GROUP_CONCAT` that contain the ID not just the single match e.g.

```
SELECT p.id,
p.title,
GROUP_CONCAT(a.author_id) as 'aus'
FROM publications p INNER JOIN authors a
    ON p.publication_id = a.publication_id
WHERE a.author_id = 2
GROUP BY p.id,p.title
```

would return

```
id    title     aus
1     A         1,2,3
2     B         1,2
3     C         2
4     D         2
5     E         2,3
```

as opposed to just 3 & 4.

I've tried various combinations of `HAVING` and `WHERE` clauses on both the a.author_id column and the `GROUP_CONCAT` product.

Comment: aggregate function without group by clause ?

Comment: ah sorry yes I do have that i just simplified to post. Have updated the question

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT returns a single field containing a comma separated list of values, while WHERE / HAVING check for a field that equals a particular value. You can use FIND_IN_SET but this means it is being forced to check through the values in the field without the benefit of indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to use a self join of the authors table, with the 2nd join checking for author_id of 2.

Guessing a bit at your data but something like this

```
SELECT p.id,
        p.title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(a.author_id) as 'aus'
FROM publications p 
INNER JOIN authors a ON p.publication_id = a.publication_id
INNER JOIN authors a2 ON p.publication_id = a2.publication_id
WHERE a2.author_id = 2
GROUP BY p.id,
        p.title
```

Comment: Thanks I have tested this out and it's the fastest method

Answer (score 6):

You should use FIND_IN_SET in HAVING clause.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, GROUP_CONCAT(a.author_id) as aus
FROM publications p INNER JOIN authors a
    ON p.publication_id = a.publication_id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY p.id,p.title
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('2', aus) > 0
```

Comment: This works but I have accepted Kickstarts answer as it is faster

Comment: This answer works with integers which may cause confusion - in part because   FIND_IN_SET takes strings as both parameters and one may think 1 is in set(3, 4, 2091, 27), but, it does not think 1 is in 2091, so it works. Anyone know why?

Comment: @fungusanthrax it works because [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/) treats the second string as a coma-separated list of strings (an actual set of `'3', '4', '2091', '27'` for this example), it doesn't work like `POSITION`